# change display format for all string variables to as short as possible

Tags: printf, stata

After `compress`ing my data, I have several string variables with storage type `str4` or `str1` and format `%9s`. I would like to revert them all to the default display format, which `help dformat` reports should be `%#s` for `str#`. Is there a quick way to do this?

This is the structure of my best guess:

```
ds, has(type string)
foreach v of varlist `r(varlist)' {
  format `v' 
}
```

This does not work because, instead of reformatting to the default value with this command, the `format` function just displays the format.

---

A reproducible example:

```
clear
input str50 mystr
"b"
"a"
end

compress
format myst
```

This is the situation I was confronted with. I am not sure if it applies beyond `strL` formatted variables. (Roberto suspects that it does not; see comments.)

*Addendum*. My goal here was to make `browse`-ing my data easier. It seems that `format` is respected in the browser (truncating to length of one for %1s, say), while it is overridden by the actual length of the string when printing to the console.

Comment: `compress` automatically changes the display format for strings to an appropriate one. What do you gain by changing it? What does "revert them all to default display format" mean? What is `dformat`? Do you mean `format`?

Comment: It did not change the display format to the appropriate one. I don't know what `dformat` is, actually, I just saw it online and the command works. Thanks for having a look at it, Roberto.

Comment: I'm still lost. I don't understand your request but maybe Nick's answer is of help to you. My point (again), is that if you use `compress`, display formats for strings will change accordingly. This you can see running the example in `help compress` and using `describe`.

Comment: Yeah, "revert" was the wrong word. Nonetheless, this is what I saw with my data. I will try to make an example. By "default display" I mean exactly what is written in the doc as "default formats" for each storage type.

Comment: I understand now what you mean by "default" but still: won't `compress` do that for you? I think the answer is "yes", running the example in `help compress`, but to be honest, I don't use it much. Please correct if I'm wrong. The exception seems to be with `strL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised that you seem surprised, as with your syntax the `format` command (not function) does indeed just display the format, as is documented. Incidentally, you don't need a loop to do that as `format` will take a *varlist* as argument:

```
. clear

. set obs 1
obs was 0, now 1

. foreach t in a b c {
2. gen `t' = "`t'"
3. }

. format a b c

variable name  display format
-----------------------------
a              %9s
b              %9s
c              %9s
-----------------------------
```

Joshing apart, I think you need just one line here, which is something like

```
. format a b c %1s
```

or

```
. format a b c %-1s
```

to signal which justification. Stata doesn't truncate displayed strings just because they don't match the string display format; it might well truncate strings because there isn't space to show them, but (I'm naturally open to counter-examples) the above display formats for variables will do well for most purposes.

EDIT: The following device may help.

```
  gen length = 0 

  ds, has(type string) 
  quietly foreach v in `r(varlist)' {
      replace length = length(`v') 
      su length, meanonly 
      format `v' %`r(max)'s 
  }

  drop length
```

Comment: "structure of my best guess" -- not what I actually expected to work. I wanted to demonstrate that I had thought through part of the solution (as is commonly expected on SO). Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: "Stata doesn't truncate display strings just because they don't match the display format" Ah, that's good to know! Thanks

Comment: Try this: `di %1s "Frank asks lots of Stata questions"`.

Comment: I've tweaked the wording slightly. Display of strings with numeric content will often, but not always, obey any numeric format you specify.

Comment: Gah, unaccepting. Sorry -- I see that `list` and `display` don't truncate (as you say), but `browse` does, displaying my variables as `C...`, for example. So, uh, hoping someone can answer that. I'll edit the question instead of making a new one. I'm assuming you don't mind?

Comment: OK; there is a suggestion for you in the answer.